# Shift signal in frequency domain

Tags: frequency-spectrum

I want to shift the signal in frequency domain without going back to the time domain.

Is it enough to shift the samples of the spectrum only? How?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to turn a time domain signal $x(t)$ into $x(t-T)$ where $T$ is the shift, but you have access to the Fourier transform $X(f)$, and you don't want to calculate the inverse transform? If that's the case, you should use the phase shift property, which means you should multiply $X(f)$ by $\exp(j 2 \pi f T)$.

Comment: No i want to shift the frequency component of the signal, not shifting the time of the signal.

Comment: Ok, so all you need is translating the frequency axis and looking at $X(f-f_0)$ instead of $X(f)$? Is this for some sort of pitch shifting application?

Comment: What useful is to shift the spectrum if you dont want to get back in time???. Can you clarify that? As indicated, the trivial operation $X(f-f_0)$ dont have any great value if you dont intend to take the IFT.

Comment: Is this related to your other question, [Shift band-limited signal in frequency domain](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/35684/shift-band-limited-signal-in-frequency-domain) ?

Comment: No it is not related

Answer (score 2):

If you merely want to shift spectral samples up in frequency, the process is fairly simple.  Let's say your DFT comprises the eight complex-valued samples X[0], X[1], X[2], X[3], X[4], X[5], X[6], X[7] and you want to shift them upward in frequency by two samples. The new shifted Y[m] spectral samples would be:

Y[0] = X[6]

Y[1] = X[7]

Y[2] = X[0]

Y[3] = X[1]

Y[4] = X[2]

Y[5] = X[3]

Y[6] = X[4]

Y[7] = X[5]

You'll notice that the shifting could be described as a "circular shift" because of the sample wrap-around behavior. If you want to shift your original X[m] sequence downward in frequency by three samples. The new shifted Y[m] spectral samples would be:

Y[0] = X[3]

Y[1] = X[4]

Y[2] = X[5]

Y[3] = X[6]

Y[4] = X[7]

Y[5] = X[0]

Y[6] = X[1]

Y[7] = X[2]

Comment: Very clear and nice explanation +1

Comment: Shouldn't you shift the negative frequencies in the "other" direction though? So the frequency upshift procedure would be to split the spectrum at $(N-1)/2$, and all bins above $(N-1)/2$ will move right and those below $(N-1)/2$ will move left. Samples falling off the edges $0$ and $N-1$ would be discarded.

Comment: @Atul Ingle: Perform a DFT on some real-valued time samples, implement the frequency-domain shifting as you have described it, compute the inverse DFT on your shifted freq samples, and then compare your new time samples (which will be complex-valued  to your original time samples. Does your freq-domain shifting scheme produce predictable results in the time domain?

Comment: @RichardLyons here's what I mean: https://gist.github.com/ingle/7c369a5538452bf94a7c5883b9df72f6
Your method will produce a complex signal because the spectrum will not remain "symmetrical" any more.

Comment: @Atul Ingle: Sorry, I'm not able to read your software code. Because there are no mathematical equations on the web page I do understand what processing you are performing. Also, I don't understand the frequency-axes values or why there are four spectral components in your spectral plots.

Comment: This comment refers to your question about the book used as an example in a now deleted question (I can't comment there since the question has been deleted by its owner) . I don't know the book. Your only chance is to leave a comment below another question of that user called ROHAN PAUL.

Comment: @RichardLyons Here's a simpler example with a sine wave of length 8. I applied your circular shift method and the result was complex. However if I apply the "split shift" method I get the correct result with upshifted frequency. http://imgur.com/3QiXKO0

Comment: @Atul Ingle: OK, I now understand what you were saying. Your explanation is very clear. Your method of shifting is different than what I thought Mahdi was asking about. I may have misunderstood his question. Good job Atul!